# c# Normalized power for Polar cycle

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
List<int> NPower = new List<int>();

List<double> list = new List<double>();



try
{
    for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < i + 30; n++)
        {
            NPower.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i + n].Cells[6].Value));
        }
    }
    average = NPower.Average();

    total = Math.Pow(average, 4);
    NPower.Clear();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    average = NPower.Average();

    NP = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(average, (1.0 / 3.0)));


    label19.Text = "Normalised Power:  " + NP.ToString();
    NPower.Clear();
}
```

Hi so i'm trying to calculate the normalized power for a cycling polar cycle. I know that for the normalized power you need to:

1) starting at the 30 s mark, calculate a rolling 30 s average (of the preceeding time points, obviously).

2) raise all the values obtained in step #1 to the 4th power.

3) take the average of all of the values obtained in step #2.

4) take the 4th root of the value obtained in step #3.

I think i have done that but the normalized power comes up with 16 which isnt correct. Could anyone look at my code to see if they could figure out a solution. Thankyou, sorry for my code i'm still quite new to this so my code might be in the incorrect format.

Comment: You said fourth root but then you use 1/3. And then you do that... inside a catch block? I don't understand why. If there's an exception in the try block then chances are it's not correct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that I understand your requirements or code completely, but a few things I noticed:

1. Since you're supposed to start taking the rolling average after 30 seconds, shouldn't `i` be initialized to 30 instead of 1?
2. Since it's a rolling average, shouldn't `n` be initialized to the value of `i` instead of 0?
3. Why is the final result calculated inside a `catch` block?
4. Shouldn't it be `Math.Pow(average, (1.0 / 4.0))` since you want the fourth root, not the third?

Comment: -1 Do not post comments as answers please. Especially not if your comment is nothing but questions. Questions are not answers...

Comment: The OP's question was what was causing their code to produce the incorrect result, and I saw several things that seemed to be likely causes. Since the question had ambiguity, though, I couldn't state it with certainty, so I phrased my answer in the form of questions.